# iPhone app crashes when double tapping textfield in WKWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a three textfields Email ID, Mobile Number, Name in webview. When I enter an invalid email id and move to mobile number textfield a validation popup is displayed "Please Enter Email ID". However, when double tapping the mobile number textfield the app crashes and I get the below crash report.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <WebValidationBubbleViewController: 0x131ddf7e0> that is already being presented by <Mx_ScreenController: 0x1330a4800>.'

Please help me to resolve it

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [example] showing what you have already tried and what part is not working. See also [ask].